# Can't get (this) jQuery selector working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a repeating class called "a.add_mycrate" on my page.
This script targets the clicked instance (this) only and deals with it.

Here is my JS :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(document).on('click', "a.add_mycrate", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var title = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
    var artwork = jQuery(this).attr('data-artwork');
    var stream = jQuery(this).attr('data-stream');
    var download = jQuery(this).attr('data-download');

    var data = {
                'action': 'addToCrate',
                'security': jQuery( '#crate-nonce' ).val(),
                'podtitle' : title,
                'podartwork' : artwork,
                'podstream' : stream,
                'podsave' : download
               };                  

    jQuery.post(myCrate.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        jQuery('a.add_mycrate', this).html(response);

        alert(response);
    });              
  });
});
```

This is how the actual links are being rendered on the page (in case it helps) :

```
<a class="add_mycrate" href="#" data-title="Title Goes Here" data-artwork="artwork.jpg" data-stream="myfile.mp3" data-download="link/to/download">Add To Crate</a>
```

The (this) selector is working fine when grabbing the data for the vars but I can't get the code in the response to target (this) instance of "a.add_mycrate". This is the line I'm having trouble with :

```
jQuery('a.add_mycrate', this).html(response);
```

I know I must be doing it wrong but all the things I've tried from looking around on here aren't working. Any suggestions?

P.S. Not relevant to the question, but I'm using "jQuery" instead of "$" as it's being run on a wordpress site in case anybody was wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues:

`this` inside the `$.post` callback is not what you think it is. It has a different scope context than `this` in the outer event handler.
Store a reference to `this` outside of the ajax to use inside it

```
var $this = jQuery(this);
jQuery.post(myCrate.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        $this.html(response);
});
```

This will also solve a problem with:

```
jQuery('a.add_mycrate', this).html(response);
```

The second argument is the *"context"*. If you were assuming that `this` was the element , the context argument makes it the same as :

```
jQuery(this).find('a.add_mycrate');
```

So you would be looking for the element inside itself. Both issues are solved by storing the element reference outside of the ajax and inserting html directly into stored element

EDIT : How to use $ in wordpress noConflict() instead of having to use `jQuery` for everything:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // can use `$` for all your code inside the ready handler
    // when you pass it in as argument
})
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation and yes, of course it works. Thanks Charlietfl ;)

Comment: see extra note about how to use `$`

Comment: Yes I use the $ wrap in virtually all of my other functions, just wrote this one using jQuery for no particular reason. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put `this` in a variable called `elm` before `post` and then change the html of `elm` like following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click', "a.add_mycrate", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var title = jQuery(this).attr('data-title');
        var artwork = jQuery(this).attr('data-artwork');
        var stream = jQuery(this).attr('data-stream');
        var download = jQuery(this).attr('data-download');
        var elm = this;

        var data = {
            'action': 'addToCrate',
            'security': jQuery( '#crate-nonce' ).val(),
            'podtitle' : title,
            'podartwork' : artwork,
            'podstream' : stream,
            'podsave' : download
        };                  

        jQuery.post(myCrate.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            jQuery(elm).html(response);
            alert(response);
        });              
    });
});
```

Comment: `this` is not the element